# Can't see my App package in Android>data folder of my phone

Tags: android, package, monkeyrunner, monkey

I am working on Android Studio and I cannot see my package inside **Android>Data** folder of my device when I run `apk` on it. I am unable to run monkey without it. I have also mentioned `installLocation="auto"` in manifest and gave `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission still cannot see my package name.

Answer (score 10):

**This is an old question, but I decided to answer it for future readers.**

To be able to see your package in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/` you first have to write to it (create a file or folder in that directory).

You can do so by doing the following:

```
File directoryToStore;
    directoryToStore = getBaseContext().getExternalFilesDir("TestFolder");
    if (!directoryToStore.exists()) {
        if (directoryToStore.mkdir()) ; //directory is created;
    }
```

---

Once you have created a folder like above you will be able to see the following:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/yourPackageName/files/TestFolder/
```

---

I think what [@Devsil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32565349/8199772) meant was that only rooted devices can access `data/data/packageName`. Two completely different directories.

Comment: Thanks. This one was did infact created a package folder for my application that  I am trying to run on an actual device.

Comment: TNX that work, but why should we do that?

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper Because if you don't make the directory, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I believe in order to get into the Data folder your device will need to be rooted. Otherwise nothing will be shown there when you attempt to browse to that location.

Comment: go to FileManager>Android>Data . You can see package of different Apps